# LISP Need some helps to solve one exsercise with LIST

Tags: list, lisp

This is what I must do! I have a lot of list and I must return list without integer.

```
(functInt '(f 3 (v) (((7))) n ()))
```

-------->

```
(f (v) ((())) n ())
```

This is my code:

```
(defun functInt (list)
  (cond ((atom list) (if (not(integerp list)) list))
        ((null (cdr list)) (functInt (car list)))
        (T (cons (functInt (car list)) (functInt (cdr list))))))
```

But what I get is `(F NIL V NIL N)`
How can I correct my code to get the output that I want?

Answer (score 4):

One of the problems is that

```
(if (not (integerp list)) list)
```

returns `nil` when `list` is an integer, so you're replacing integers with `nil`.

I think the only way to get this right is by assuming that no-one will ever call your function on a non-list value. Then you can rewrite it in the form

```
(defun functInt (x)
  (cond ((atom x) x)
        ((integerp (car x)) FOO)
        (t BAR)))
```

where I leave the expressions to substitute for `FOO` and `BAR` as exercises. `(functInt 3)` will still return `3`, but that violates the function's contract.

Note that `(atom nil)` is true, so you don't need a special case for `(null x)`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be helpful to not try to do all this in a single function, but use a higher-order function to solve the general case and then only fill in a very simple function for the specific case. This is one suitable higher-order function:

```
(defun tree-mapcan (function tree)
  (if (listp tree)
      (list (mapcan (lambda (elt) (tree-mapcan function elt))
                    tree))
      (funcall function tree)))
```